# npm для создания редактора кода

Tags: npm

Нужен пакет npm, который позволит превратить браузер в полноценный редактор кода (пример, VS Code, с подсветкой синтаксиса, как в js).

Comment: Вставляйте `<iframe>` с https://vscode.dev/ и не парьтесь :)

Comment: Неужели не удалось нагуглить ни одного редактора?

Comment: как видите, что за вопрос глупый